# Upload from offline HTML5 app when network available

Tags: html, scheduled-tasks, offlineapps, network-state

Wow, my problem seems like it must be so common that I must just be missing something really obvious but here goes:

Is there any way to trigger/schedule a dormant offline HTML5 app to run either:

- when network comes available,
- or regularly.

I want to create an offline HTML5 app that will record details of a delivery (item description, recipient's name, photo, timestamp, etc). The data will be written to local storage (the photo converted to base64). If the app has network then the delivery data will be uploaded to a remote server. If the app does not have network then, even if the user powers the device down, next time the device is up and has network, I need the app to do the upload without any action by the user.

I've searched and found nothing. I'm guessing that offline apps only get run-time when in the foreground? If someone could confirm that then that would at least be good to know, even if it's not what I'd like to hear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Background sync, exactly what I was after (although in 2016 it was Chrome-only):
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync